# iOS - how to send one location update "right now" when the app is in the foreground?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I want to do one location update immediately when the app moves to the foreground (basically like a check in). The purple location marker on the top should appear momentarily and then go off. Can anybody point me in the right direction for this?

EDIT: What I have tried so far -

```
[m_coreLocationMan startUpdatingLocation];
```

What happens here is that the location update does take place, and the purple arrow appears, but never goes off when the update is done. I need for it to disappear after a location update is done.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the core location documentation?

Comment: put that code on applicationDidBecomeActive on your app delegate and wait, or put it on applicationWillBecomeActive.

Comment: once you update the location call [m_coreLocationMan stopUpdatingLocation]; to turn off the location events.

Comment: i have done that already, but the icon doesn't seem to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to it. It is really strange but I hope someone who runs into it might find this to be helpful -

I created a new bundle id and the error disappeared! If I use the old one, I still see the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your location (didUpdateToLocation:... delegate method), simply stop updating the location. I assume m_coreLocationMan is a CLLocationManager...

```
[m_coreLocationMan stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: I do that, but somehow the purple icon does not go :(

Comment: Oh dear. I'm doing exactly the same thing and it does disappear (after a few seconds, anyway). I don't know what else to suggest, you could perhaps update your question with a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the location marker dot on a google map?  You can use

```
yourMapName.showsUserLocation = NO
```

to make it disappear, but you should understand that this is an MKMapView method, not part of Core Location.

[MKMapView Class Reference - showsUserLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Comment: Nope. not talking about that. I am talking about the purple location marker in the top bar of the iphone right next to the battery level.

Comment: Do you have any other applications that use Location Services enabled?  If *anything* is using them, even if an application is closed but has the system monitoring regions for it, the arrow will be purple for all apps.  Only turning off the very last thing using Location Services will remove the purple arrow.

Comment: I checked that already. everything else is off and if i delete my app off the phone the purple thing goes off immediately

Comment: Assuming you haven't registered any regions for monitoring and haven't signed up for significant location changes, you'd need to post code to see where the problem is